# Gnome Shell task switcher and Wine applications: only generic icon displayed

Tags: 12.04, gnome, wine, icons

When switching applications with the task switcher in Gnome Shell, only the generic "glass of wine" icon is displayed. This is the same for all Wine apps I tried. Icons in the activities menu are fine.

You can see the problem in this screenshot:
[image: Wrong icon for Wine app]

Is there a way to change this?

PS: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:
There does not seem to be an easy way to fix this.
phoibos found [this discussion](http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-bugs/2011-May/275441.html) linking to to [Gnome bug report #649087](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649087).
We might see this working in a future Gnome version (current is 3.2.1 in Ubuntu 12.04).

Now follows the answer for the **initially misunderstood question**:

If you have two or more different wine programs running the wine icon should get extended and show a small triangle below it. From there you can switch programs with <`> shortcut. That is  plus the left key of 1, above the  key.

Now if you are not having the triangle then wine is only seeing your program as one single window. In this case I don't think there is an easy way around..

[image: Switching to wine windows]

Comment: Yes, I get this triangle for the subwindows. But I want to get te right icons for the individual Wine programs. In my example screenshot, I had foobar2000 open - the icon for this program is displayed correctly on the desktop, yet in the task-switcher, I only see the generic icon.

Comment: Uh ok, sorry I misunderstood your question. It is not trivial as the running program is always wine, and the shown icon belongs to it. For example, what icon should be shown if you are running two different programs in wine? The one that is selected? This sounds more like a wine improvement and for this you are better off asking in the wine forum.

Comment: Yes, technically it's just another wine program, but in Gnome 2, or Unity, the actual icons are displayed. Well I found out there are already bug reports for wine and gnome-shell, both uncomfirmed: [http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-bugs/2011-May/275441.html](http://www.winehq.org/pipermail/wine-bugs/2011-May/275441.html)